# Estimate the maximum possible error in the approximation - Taylor Polynomials

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given the following example.

Estimate the maximum possible error in the approximation.

$cos(x) = T_{\displaystyle4,\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2}}$ for $x \in \left[\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2} -0.2, \frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2} + 0.2\right]$. $\\$

$R_{\displaystyle4,\frac{\pi}{2}}(x) \le \frac{\displaystyle|-\sin(z)|}{\displaystyle5!} |x-\frac{\pi}{2}|^5$ $\\$

$\Rightarrow R_{\displaystyle4,\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2}}(x) \le \frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle 5!}(0.2)^5 $

I don't understand how the example went from $|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|^5$ to $(0.2)^5$. Please specify the logical reasoning behind this and exactly how it is achieved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\dfrac{\pi}{2}-0.2\le x\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}+0.2$$

and that

$$  \cos(x)\approx 1-\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^4}{24}$$

Thus we know that

$$ \dfrac{\pi}{2}-0.2\le x\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}+0.2$$

from which it follows that

$$ -0.2\le x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\le 0.2$$

One should point out, however, that since this is an alternating series, a better estimation of the error would be to use the next term of the series to get $$ R<\left\vert\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^6}{6!}\right\vert\le\dfrac{(0.2)^6}{720} $$

Comment: How did you get $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-0.2\le \frac{\pi}{2}-x\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}+0.2$ ?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I don't mean you made an error - I genuinely don't understand the reasoning behind the calculations for the error approximation. Note that at the bottom of my post I stated that I do not understand how the example went from $|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|^5$ to $(0.2)^5$. This is the specific concept that I am seeking clarification on.

Comment: No, I actually made an error--more like a senior moment.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales what does the 'alternating series' aspect have to do with adding another term (as opposed to the many other cases where more terms give better error) ?

Comment: The $0.2$ represents the maximum possible value for $\left\vert \frac{\pi}{2}-x\right|$ for any $x$ lying in the given interval.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Why do we choose 0.2 = $|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|$, though? We could have chosen -0.1 or some where else in the interval.

Comment: Because you are looking for the upper bound and any other value for x would be less than that.

Comment: @cladelpino Thanks. And why exactly do we specifically want the upper bound?

Comment: Because this is written in your question:   *Estimate the maximum possible error in the approximation.* :)

Comment: @cladelpino Ok, I see. Thanks. So this is the largest possible error for our estimation using the taylor polynomial?

Comment: Yes. In this particular case, because there is an "easy" upper bound for the "derivative" (-sin(x)).

Comment: Well, you provided the $0.2$ in your question. You could ask a similar question for $0.1$ or any other value if need be. The idea is that a Taylor polynomial provides good approximations only for values of $x$ 'near' the value around which it is expanded. So if you wanted a good approximation for $x$ near $\frac{\pi}{2}$ you would not want to expand the series about $0$. If wanted to estimate $\cos(22)$ with a Taylor polynomial you would probably want to expand it around $7\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Lagrange form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) for the remainder.

There is a value of the independent variable in the interval $\xi$ for which $-sin(\xi)(x−π2)^5\over{5!}$ is **equal** to the remainder.

The guarantee is that $\xi\in[a,xEval]$ where a is the "base point", and xEval is the point in which you are approximating the function.

Therefore, the maximum possible absolute value for the remainder comes from locating the maximum for $|-sin(x)|, x\in [xEval,a]$ and multiplying it by ${|xEval-a|^5}\over{5!}$

The maximum for $|sin(x)|$ is 1.

And $|xEval-a|=0.2$ for "both" intervals considered in your question $[-0.2,\pi/2]$ and $[\pi/2,0.2]$